# Why I can't flush the input stream properly using std::cin.ignore?

Tags: c++, inputstream

I've used to clear the input buffer this way:

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

std::cin.clear();
```

And it works just fine. but now I don't know why this doesn't work?

```
int main(){

    std::vector<int> v;
    for(int i; std::cin >> i; )
        v.push_back(i);

    std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );
    std::cin.clear();

    int x;
    std::cout << "x: ";
    std::cin >> x;
    std::cout << x << '\n';

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Input:
4
5
7
^d

Output:
x: 0

- Why I am not prompted to input `x`?
  -I've also cleared the stream before calling `std::cin.ignore`:

  ```
    std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );
    std::cin.clear();
  ```

But the problem persists!

PS: I am using g++ (GCC) 10.3.1 20210422 (Red Hat 10.3.1-1) on fedora 33. and Code::blocks 20.03

- If I enter a non integer like a character e.g: 'a' it works just fine but if I enter `EOF` (`CTRL+D`) it doesn't work!

Comment: You can't flush a stream that is in an error state.  You have to `clear` that state first.  There should be a dupe for this, let me check

Comment: You mean I should call `std::cin.clear()` first? If so then it doesn't wok too. e.g: `std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');`

Comment: Yes.  `ignore` won't work if the steam is in an error state (EOF in this case)

Comment: @NathanOliver: But It doesn't work too!!

Comment: [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0fda0f77bf6bd8c9) doesn't let you input for `x`?

Comment: @NathanOliver: yes I can't. I get this: `g++ -std=c++2a -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
x: 32671`

Comment: What are you giving as input (to the vector) to signal the 'error condition'? (I guess you need to enter something that is not a valid `int`, like a letter; just typing a line of space-separated integers, then <enter>, won't end the loop.)

Comment: `^d` (I presume that means control+D) ends the input stream.  The input is kaput.

Comment: Usually, once you have terminated the standard input stream, it stays terminated. There may be some platform-specific way to close and reopen it.

Comment: @molbdnilo: Sure! and what matters me a lot is that a code like this already worked normally but now it doesn't!!!  does this mean that my GCC is brken or something like that?

Comment: "but if I enter EOF (CTRL+D) it doesn't work!" Well, yes; if you tell the program explicitly that you are never again going to give it any more input, then code that tries to ask you for more input will not work. I don't understand why this is surprising or confusing. "a code like this already worked normally but now it doesn't" I can guarantee you that code that "already worked normally" was not "like this", in an important way. But we cannot possibly tell you exactly what is different in other code, unless we actually see it.

Comment: Where the code says `std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );`, exactly what do you think this means? What do you think is its intended purpose? What does that imply about how to provide the input? (Hint: why does the code say `'\n'`, and not, say, some special end-of-file constant?)

Comment: @Maestro: Are you sure that when this worked, you weren't hitting `Enter`, rather than `Ctrl-D`?